# Ram Solutions Group, genuine or scammer?

Tags: shares, scams, private-company

I have received an email from RAM SOLUTIONS GROUP offering to buy my shares at a higher price than I paid.

How do I check this company is genuine?

Comment: Are they publicly traded shares? If so, why are they not just buying them on an exchange?

Comment: Your location? Contacting you by email is illegal in EU unless they have your contact from previous business dealings.

Comment: I've deleted a bunch of comments that are really discussing an answer (which was previously posted in abbreviated form in a comment). If you really must challenge the answer, comment on that answer instead, but any extended discussion will be subject to deletion as usual.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Things to look for:

- They contacted you first. You always have to ask yourself how they came by your contact. If they have a really good product, they would not have to SPAM to sell it. *Clarification, due to some comments: By "they contacted you first" I mean you do not know them, it is not something forwarded by your bank/broker etc. and you never purchased anything from them.*
- They have insufficient info on their homepage. Who is CEO, what legal form does this Company have, where is it registered. Which financial authorities govern it?
- Do they have a normal telephone-number? Does somebody answer if you call?
- They reside outside of your jurisdiction. Always a warning sign - if you have any complaints it will be very hard and expensive to take legal action.

Comment: This is a good answer, but @MSalter's answer also contains valid points.  If the offer is part of a buyout or a settlement, there will be details about that with the offer, but that offer could originate from any number of legitimate third parties.  There are banks and non-financial companies that intermediate such transactions or just expedite a portion of it (like finding shareholders).  In addition to your points, it's worth looking at the detail of what they sent.  It's probably a scam, but it's worth remembering that in the financial markets the legit folks are not great at looking legit.

Answer (score 19):

I have received non-scam emails containing an offer to buy my shares, but (1) they were from the bank that manages my shares, and (2) it was in reaction to a public offer for those shares. So it was a higher price than I paid, but that is normal in a take-over bid.

Further signs of a non-scam bid: there is a public, legal document describing the offer, and the buyer mentions its own bank or financial institute. There will almost certainly be a provision that the offer is conditional on enough current share owners selling, and a reasonable cut-off date after which the bidder will announce whether it received enough offers.

Comment: *I have received non-scam emails* - The point is, you contacted them first, back when you opened your account.

Comment: @Daniel: Sort of. It's not my bank who is making the offer, and I did not contact the company who made the offer. But the bank is a trusted _and regulated_ intermediary.

Comment: @MSalters Location? EU laws prohibit this.

Comment: @Sentinel, is it?  Can I genuinely not contact a financial institution and ask "please convey this offer to all of your clients who you know hold shares in corporation X"?

Comment: @Mark. You are right, I misunderstood MSalters comment "It is not my bank making the offer". I am not clear now on who emailed whom.

Comment: @Sentinel: Netherlands. The bank emailed me to forward a public offer. They don't have a direct financial interest, other than receiving a broker fee when I sell the shares (to the bidder or anyone else).

Comment: @MSalters. I see, then no EU anti-spam laws do not apply, IMO

Comment: @MSalters: The point is, you got the mail from your Bank. You can easily verify by calling your bank and asking *Is this offer legit?*. You will probably make the transaction through the bank. An they will have some liability for it. That is entirely different than OP´s situation.

Comment: @Sentinel: EU-Laws don´t forbid B-to-B offers (Some acquisition company to Bank) and also not B-to-C offers (Bank to MSalters) when you have an existing relationship to that customer.

Comment: @Daniel: It's not a bank-to-consumer offer. The bank isn't offering, they're just passing the message. Also, consumer/customer law doesn't really apply here. I am of course a natural person, but as a share holder I am significantly less protected than as a consumer.

Comment: The EU-Laws do not regulate on making an offer, but on making unsolicited contact. The Bank is responsible for making contact in this case. (unless I am mistaken and you really got a mail from the buyer, addressed directly to you)

Comment: @Daniel. Agreed. If bank contacted MSalters and did not share MSalters info with buyer, then it is legit